# How do I repeatedly move an image by 1 pixel?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have a method that is moving a UIImageView called `shootImg` across the screen:

```
-(IBAction)shoot{
if (appDelegate.shootInt > 0) {
    if (direction == 1) {
            shootImg.center = CGPointMake(shootImg.center.x+1, shootImg.center.y);
            appDelegate.shootInt = appDelegate.shootInt - 1;
            shootLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", appDelegate.shootInt];
                }
```

This does seem to work. But it only moves `shootImage` 1 pixel. What I want to do is make it repeatedly move 1 pixel. I tried a while loop but that didn't seem to work. I'm not using cocos2d or anything like that and if you need to see more code just ask.

Thanks :)

Comment: It would be better if you showed us the context of where you're using the shoot method.

Comment: Well it's just a UIButton. What do you mean by context?

Comment: I see now. The function above is just a response to a button press?

Comment: Yeah, and shootimg is a UIImageView

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
shootImg.center = CGPointMake(shootImg.center.x+appDelegate.shootInt, shootImg.center.y);
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

you can use this to animate the motion of ur image over 0.25 secs. But if you want to change the duration or any other animation properties then refer the doc.

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/uiview_class/uiview/uiview.html

Answer (score -1):

How about making your own method in moving your object.. and inside your if statement:

a loop the calls this method: 
[self performSelector:@selector(methodname) withObject:nil afterDelay:1]; *//this calls the method that moves your object every after 1 second..* 
as many times as you want..

Comment: Your post is incomprehensible. I suggest you clean up your language and [format your post a little, including the code](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/editing-help).